# "Not an ARRAY reference" when looping a json file - Perl

Tags: perl, loops, cgi

I'm trying to read a json file thru a foor loop, but I get an error "Not an ARRAY reference" this is the code than I'm using;

```
$json_text = JSON::XS->new->utf8->encode ($return); 
my $decoded_file = decode_json $json_text;

for my $items (@{$decoded_file}) {

}
```

$decoded_file:

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'data' => {
                   'id' => 0,   
                   'type' => 'car',
                   'details' => [
                                 {
                                   'year' => '2001',
                                   'color' => 'red', 
                                 }
                               ],
                   'status' => 'Y'
                 },
```

Comment: You'll also need to show us the `$return` or `$json_text` being used as input.

Comment: That code runs without errors when I fill in the blanks with the data that the rest of the code anticipates.

Comment: @Tanktalus $return is a hash reference and and i have updated the question so now yo ucan se the value of $json_text

Comment: Please, show us the output of `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($return)`.

Comment: @Pedro, that text won't decode, so it must be incomplete. If the input is a hash, the output will be a hash, not an array, and thus, yeah, it's not going to work.

Comment: @Tanktalus i see the problem, I thought that by using enconde I was also changing the type to an array

Comment: @Dada It mean that I'll have to chance that first in order to loop thru the data

Comment: What you claim isn't true. Please produces a minimal, runnable demontration of your problems. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

What you claim isn't true.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $decoded_file = [
      {
        'data' => {
                    'status' => 'Y',
                    'id' => 0,
                    'type' => 'car',
                    'details' => [
                                   {
                                     'year' => '2001',
                                     'color' => 'red'
                                   }
                                 ]
                  }
      }                      # Added this.
    ];                       # Added this.

for my $items (@{$decoded_file}) {

}

print "ok\n";
```

produces

```
ok
```

In what you showed us, `$decoded_file` holds a reference to an array, so your loop is indeed what you should be using.

Comment: Still getting the same error and thats what I don't understand..... $return is a hash ref and $decode_file is also a hash ref and I don't know why :/
 Im using ref($return) ref($decoded_file) and they both output ref(HASH(0x4884)).....the daya in $return look exacly as the one on $decoded_file

Comment: Re "*Still getting the same error*", And your Question still doesn't demonstrate your problem. We can't help you until you actually demonstrate your problem. See [mcve]